# Latest dotnet-ef scaffolding doesn't accept --namespace or --context-namespace as valid parameters

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

It seems the latest dotnet ef tools (v3.1.3) documentation on Microsoft's site list having the following parameters for dbcontext scaffolding:

- -n or --namespace to specify the default namespace of all generated classes
- --context-namespace to specify the namespace of the generated DbContext file

However, when I attempt to add those commands to my dotnet-ef command, it says they are not known commands. And I am using Oracle EFF which only works with Core 2.1 so I'm wondering if that is the issue as well?

[image]

Here is the version I'm using:

[image: ty]

We like to keep the DbContext file separate from the generated PODO classes so the only work around we have is to generate all the classes in the project namespace where the PODO's will reside, then move the generated DbContext class file to a different project and change the namespace.

It's very strange that Microsoft's documents point out the two options exist, but when I check on my machine running the latest .NET Core 3.1 SDK and have the 3.1.3 Command Line tools installed, it's not there.

Is this something that works with possibly EFF6 only? We're trying to build any new apps using .NET Core as we are moving towards container services such as Docker and Kubernetes at my work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use 5.0.0 of the dotnet-ef tool to use these options, which is currently in preview. I ran this command to update to a pre-release version and I'm now able to use them.

`dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.0-preview.4.20220.10`

You'll also need to use version 5.0.0 of the EF packages in your project.

---

You can see all versions of the donet-ef tool here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ef/

The commit that added support for these flags:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/922a7709c4d5d5cf1b9a9b258623c8ef57baebfe#diff-b63a8c6540910fa14bd75aaf248e900d